# Saved Search to get the latest Child record

Tags: search, netsuite

How do i get the latest child record of a Custom Parent Record?
The Max summary type on the results will not work for me since I have to pull other details also and summary on the field does not work.

Test Data:
Date                          Percent Complete

---

1. 8/30/2023                   38
2. 7/30/2023                   40

The saved search is on the parent record.

I tried with adding a formula text to criteria :
CASE WHEN MAX({custrecordzab_rvn_revenue_detail.internalid}) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
Value 'IS' 1

this is giving me an error